I'm trying to visualize the all launch records in a dataframe on folium map
# Add marker_cluster to current site_map
site_map.add_child(marker_cluster)

# for each row in spacex_df data frame
# create a Marker object with its coordinate
# and customize the Marker's icon property to indicate if this launch was successed or failed, 
# e.g., icon=folium.Icon(color='white', icon_color=row['marker_color']
for index, record in spacex_df.iterrows():
    # TODO: Create and add a Marker cluster to the site map
    # marker = folium.Marker(...)
    coordinates=[record['Lat'],record['Long']]
    mark_color=record["marker_color"]
    marker=folium.map.Marker(
                            location=coordinates,
        popup=record['Launch Site'],
        icon=folium.Icon(color='white', icon_color=mark_color, icon='info-sign'))
    marker_cluster.add_child(marker)

site_map

problem is: TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable
I'm trying to visualize the all launch site success and failure on the folium map but doing this I get the above error .
I want a folium map that shows each launch site success and failure of all launch records.
please help me with this!

Hello, I'm using space launch site data how can I send it to you? My issue is resolved after restarting the Jupyter Notebook but I want to why this error occurred can you help me?
